# SED command in UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I want to remove below string from a file in Unix:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

The file content is exactly this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>Hello World
```

in one single continuous line.

I am using the following command to achieve the same:

```
sed s'/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>//g' myFile > myFile1
```

However, the resultant file myFile1 is still having the string.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you try escaping the quotes?

Comment: sed s'/<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>//g' myFile > myFile1 or sed s'/<\?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF\-8\'\?>//g' myFile > myFile1 doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes for the outer quotes to avoid the escape issue:

```
sed "s/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>//g" myFile > myFile1
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that it's the XML declaration line is this the first line in the file(s)? If so, you can remove the first line like this:

```
sed -i "1d" <filename>
```

The `-i` edits the file in place so will overwrite your original, while the "1d" command simply deletes a line.

However, if it's not the first line, or appears multiple times, then you can use this:

```
sed -i '/\?xml/d' <filename>
```

Again, it's editing in place and using the `d` command to delete, but this time it's deleting based on the regular expression. You might want to expand the regex a bit so that it's more targeted, but the principle is there.

You say in the comments that it's just *part* of a line that you want to remove, so in that case:

```
sed -i "s/<?xml .*?\?>//" <filename>
```

Summed up as "replace everything between "" with nothing (effectively delete it).

Comment: its not the first instance and is in between. And also part of a continuous large string: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>Hello World"

Answer (score 1):

If you search for `"string"` in a directory, it should give you the top 3 and bottom 3 occurrences of the string in all the files, and output that to an out file.

I am using:

```
grep string path-to-file | head -3 > out.log
grep string path-to-file | tail -3 >> out.log
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed '/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>/d' myfile` .

Comment: This is not working.. My file contains: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>Hello World" - exactly this string

Comment: Will try and fix that at home. On my way :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue with the quotes, you might consider using `grep -v` instead of `sed`:

```
grep -v "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" myFile > myFile1
```

But if you know that the line you don't want is always the first line in the file, the following is even easier:

```
tail -n +2 myFile > myFile1
```

Comment: grep doesn't work.. my file contains: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>Hello World" - exactly this string

Comment: Well, that's not what you wrote in your original question: "I want to remove below *line* from a file in Unix:". You did not mention that what you want to remove is only *a part of* a line.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below script.

```
sed 's/\<\?xml version\=\'1\.0\' encoding\=\'UTF\-8\'\?\>//g' myfile > myfile_new
```

Idea is to comment the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' myfile` should work